# Create/use a custom mapping API using a custom image on a website

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I'm making a website for my university where people can go online and check out where all the free food is on campus. I want the people with free food to be able to register their event, have this event stored in a database and have students be able to see all of the registered events on a campus map.

The experience would be similar to someone searching for a Wal-Mart within a 10 mile radius on Google Maps and seeing the pins drop down on all valid locations.

I just don't really know how to approach the problem of having people register their events at a particular location on campus, and then have a corresponding pin drop on the respective XY location on the campus map image. Also, I would like to use this tool for other campuses, so I'm trying to code the logic in such a way that I could apply it to any custom image basically.

Are there existing API's that can do this or is this something I would have to code on my own? I looked up a couple maps APIs but didn't really find anything I was looking for.

P.S. If it's helpful, I'm a CS major, so feel free to throw out technical terms without fear of me being able to figure it out, I just really don't know how to approach this problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic stuff actually, just kind of a big question. For the map i would use [html5 canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) probably. Use javascript to identify coordinates of where they click on the canvas element and store them in 2 integer columns in the database.

Do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps API v3 actually lets you provide custom maps while still utilizing all of their great APIs. I found a good tutorial here: https://facepunch.com/showthread.php?t=1184658